# pointwise converging sequence of continuous functions: bounding oscilation from below

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Assume It is known know that oscilation $\omega(f_n, U) > \epsilon$ for continuous functions $f_n$ and some open set $U$ starting from some $N$.
Also it is known that $f_n \to \varphi$ pointwise.
It is also safe to assume that $\overline{U}$ is compact..

Here $$\omega(f,U) = \sup_{x,y \in U} \Big|f(x) - f(y)\Big|$$

Intuitively, it seems true that  that $\omega(\varphi,U) \ge \epsilon$.

But is it actually true?

I thought that it must be possibele to find points $x_n,y_n \in \overline{U}$ such, that
$$
  \omega(f_n,U) \le \Big|f_n(x_n) - f_n(y_n) \Big|
$$

Then compute limits of converging subsequences, which exist by compactness  of $\overline{U}$. Name them $Y$ and $X$.

And Then to show that $|\varphi(Y) - \varphi(X)|$ is substantially  big by convergence and continuity arguments.
But I don't know how to do it as both argument and function depend on $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as is: **No.** We do not necessarily have that $\omega(\varphi,U) \ge \epsilon$.

For example, take

$$f_n : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{1}{nx}$$

Then, for all $n$, we have that $\, \omega(f_n, U) \ge \epsilon \,$, but since $\, f_n \xrightarrow{\text{p.w.}} 0 \,$, $\,\omega(\varphi,U) = 0$.

To me it seems that the more interesting question would be to replace $U$ with $\overline{U}$.

Comment: Ok.  I will reask my question. I think that to have $f_n$ uniformly bounded is enough to avoid this kind of results. Your answer is undoubtedly  still correct.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539518/pointwise-converging-sequence-of-continuous-functions-on-a-compact-bounding-osc

Comment: Now I think you were right about closure.